# Instantiating generic property in an abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have an abstract generic class that only accept type parameters that implement a certain interface. It is basically a data holder with a few functions:

```
public abstract class DataStructureBase<T> where T : IDataPropertyInterface
{
    public T prop1 { get; set; }
    public T prop2 { get; set; }
    public T prop3 { get; set; }
    //a few dozen more
}
```

```
public interface IDataPropertyInterface
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
}
```

All classes that implement `IDataPropertyInterface` derive from a base class:

```
public abstract class DataPropertyBase
{
    public string Name { get; init; }

    protected DataPropertyBase(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

(For example, `DataPropertyType1`, `DataPropertyType2`, etc.)

Now, there will be several extensions of the `DataStructureBase` that use these `DataPropertyBase` extending classes, for example:

```
public class DataStructureBaseType1 : DataStructureBase<DataPropertyType1>
public class DataStructureBaseType2 : DataStructureBase<DataPropertyType2>
//etc.
```

Now, problem is, `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3` and other properties should all be initialized upon `DataStructureBase`-extending class initialization, and have the same values for their `Name` property, regardless what type they were assigned. Which means that it would be a lot of redundant typing to set their names in each `DataStructureBase`-extending class. I would very much like to initialize them and set these values in the base class.

So I tried this:

```
public abstract class DataStructureBase<T> where T : IDataPropertyInterface
{
    public T prop1 { get; set; } = new("Property A");
    public T prop2 { get; set; } = new("Property B");
    public T prop3 { get; set; } = new("Property C");
    //a few dozen more
}
```

Unfortunately, such syntax throws error `Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint`, which makes sense, because even though T is constrained to `IDataPropertyInterface`, that interface does not have a constructor. Problem is that interfaces cannot declare constructors. I also tried declaring `where T : DataPropertyBase`, since that base class definitely has a constructor, but that throws the exact same error.

What can I use as a workaround to initialize these properties and assign their `Name` values in the `DataStructureBase` class, so that I don't have to type them in each class that derives from it?

Comment: Read the message carefully. It "kinda" tells you to add the ["new()" constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint).

Comment: @Fildor I should have mentioned it in my question - I am aware of that, but it enforces a parameterless constructor, while my `DataPropertyBase` should enforce using a constructor with a parameter.

Comment: This seems like a strange problem to have. Why do you need multiple occurrences of the exact same amount (“dozens”) of properties all of the same type wrapped in a class? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @JonasHøgh, I provided a refined example here to keep code to a minimum, but in the actual application, these properties (prop1, prop2, etc.) represent various bits of data that are either set by the user or application, and `DataStructureBase` is a very large and complex structure that is reused with different types and contexts. For example, it may be used as a ViewModel for UI, and hence it needs to use types that are appropriate for UI, while in the core of the application it needs whole different types. Using one universal type would mix concerns.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new `static abstract` methods in interfaces feature.

You can do this with a separate generic interface.

You new interface looks like this:

```cs
public interface IDataPropertyCreator<T> where T : IDataPropertyInterface
    // possibly add inheritance to the other interface??
{
    public static abstract T Create(string name);
}
```

Each concerete class needs to implement that interface and create an object of itself

```cs
public class DataPropertyType1 : DataPropertyBase, IDataPropertyCreator<DataPropertyType1>
{
    public DataPropertyType1(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    public static DataPropertyType1 Create(string name) => new(name);
}
```

Then your base class is simply:

```cs
public abstract class DataStructureBase<T> where T : IDataPropertyInterface, IDataPropertyCreator<T>
{
    public T prop1 { get; set; } = T.Create("Property A");
    public T prop2 { get; set; } = T.Create("Property B");
    public T prop3 { get; set; } = T.Create("Property C");
    //a few dozen more
}
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2k7Jy3)

You could also combine the interfaces, but that would mean that the interface would have a generic parameter, and you couldn't use it outside the base class.

---

If you want to avoid having to type out a constructor *and* a `Create` method, you could pull out the `Create` method into the interface (ie non-`abstract`) and use reflection, which is obviously less efficient.

```cs
public interface IDataPropertyCreator<T> where T : IDataPropertyInterface
    // possibly add inheritance to the other interface??
{
    public static T Create(string name) => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new [] {name});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can provide them via constructor?

```
public abstract class DataStructureBase<T> where T : IDataPropertyInterface
{
   public DataStructureBase(Func<T> prop1Initializer, Func<T> prop2Initializer, Func<T> prop3Initializer)
    {
        prop1 = prop1Initializer();
        prop2 = prop2Initializer();
        prop3 = prop3Initializer();
    }

    public T prop1 { get; set; }
    public T prop2 { get; set; }
    public T prop3 { get; set; }
    //a few dozen more
}
```

Comment: This could be a solution, but there are dozens of these properties. This basically would require typing each of them out 3 times (one in the DataStructureBase parameters, one in it's body, and also as properties.